# is line segment itself a convex polygon?

Tags: geometry

Is a line segment counted as a polygon? My context is I want to use do Minkowski sum of line segments, while there is a Mikowski sum algorithm for convex polygon, not sure if I can apply the same algorithm directly. It seems to be correct, but how can i prove it is correct in a regourious way?

And if so, how about the line segment in 3+ dimensions?

Would a 3d line segment consider a convex polytope?